# Iterator current is null, but why?

Tags: flutter, dart, iterator

What I want to obtain is a method of generating widgets through a predefined step sequence: widget1 -> widget 2-> widget3 -> done. And I thought of making a list of the widgets, and the way to "advance" to the next widget, would be to call `moveNext()` on the iterator. But clearly I'm missing something:

According to the docs [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterator-class.html), if moveNext() is called on the iterator and it returned true, then afterwards the `iterator.current` will not be null. When printing `print(hasAdvanced)` it returns `true`, so `iterator.current` should not be null. But it is. Why is it null? What am I missing?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreatePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreatePageState createState() => _CreatePageState();
}

class _CreatePageState extends State<CreatePageWidget> {
  List<Widget> sequence = [Text("one"), Text("two")];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    bool hasAdvanced = sequence.iterator.moveNext();
    print(hasAdvanced);
    print(sequence.iterator.current);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => sequence.iterator.current;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

> ```dart
>  bool hasAdvanced = sequence.iterator.moveNext();
>  print(hasAdvanced);
>  print(sequence.iterator.current);
> ```

You call `sequence.iterator` *twice*, but `Iterable.iterator` always returns a *new* iterator.  From the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/iterator.html):

> Returns a new `Iterator` that allows iterating the elements of this `Iterable`.
>
> ...
>
> Each time `iterator` is read, it returns a new iterator, which can be used to iterate through all the elements again. The iterators of the same iterable can be stepped through independently, ....

So even though you initially advanced the `Iterator` successfully, you then retrieve the `current` value from a *different* `Iterator`, which hasn't been advanced and therefore is still uninitialized.  You can fix this by simply keeping a reference to a single `Iterator`:

```dart
var iterator = sequence.iterator;
bool hasAdvanced = iterator.moveNext();
print(hasAdvanced);
print(iterator.current);
```

(Personally I think it is confusing and bad style for a property/getter to return new instances and that this would have been more obvious as an explicit function call. Changing the API now probably would not be worth the trouble, though.)

Comment: You're the best.